# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on User Experience breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0         13
Users destroyed                                  30          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            35      1,068
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                9        266
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          6        622
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0        448
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 1      2,176
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              147      2,128
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          0
Questions reopened                               11          4
Questions protected                               1         27
Questions migrated                               16          1
Questions merged                                  1          0
Questions flagged⁴                               22        864
Questions closed                                542        333
Question flags handled⁴                         335        551
Posts unlocked                                    0          7
Posts undeleted                                   5         36
Posts locked                                      0        142
Posts deleted⁵                                  313      1,379
Posts bumped                                      0      3,382
Comments undeleted                                6          0
Comments flagged                                  0      1,322
Comments deleted⁶                               408      1,488
Comment flags handled                           248      1,074
Answers flagged                                  62        842
Answer flags handled                            642        262
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: how does this compare to last year and what do the numbers generally mean for the community?